# Does a simple calculator have compilers?

Tags: compilers

When I input something wrong in my Casio fx-82MS calculator it shows **Syntax error** on its screen.

[image]

So does even a simple calculation on a most simple calculator like this goes through compilation phases? or is it directly the hardware that is doing all the stuff and showing the output or is there some kind of very basic software running and undergoing compilation?

Comment: Your calculator is running software which includes a parser. I don't see any need for a compiler.

Comment: and we for that software's code to execute we need compilation, right?

Comment: @HIRAKMONDAL, right. But that just means that whoever designed your calculator compiled its software's code into whatever machine code your calculator processor runs. There is no need to compile *your* input to the calculator.

Comment: ok, got it.. Thanks ... :)